# android.support.v4.view.ViewPager cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

this is my xml code:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/guide_pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
.................
```

and this is my android java code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.guide);
            // here will be crash
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.guide_pager);
}
```

in the code, there well be throw an execption:android.support.v4.view.ViewPager cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager. but only one support.v4.jar in my project. who can help me?

Comment: What Android library version are you using?

Comment: remove dependency from your java build path for support and private libraries. clean and build project again then run

Comment: Is it resolved?i am also getting same problem when trying to update system app.i have added dependency in gradle .One more thing rebooting phone works fine.Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this...

```
1) Remove the `android-support-v4.jar` from your project
2) clean the project
3) copy the jar file from `yourdrive:\android-sdks\extras\android\support\v4`
4) add this library to your project
```